# Any idea why my component isn't getting rendered in a conditional block, but renders standalone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to show a page only if the current user is logged in, else ask them to login. I am using firebase authentication to achieve this.

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import { auth } from "../../components/firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import Login from "../Login";
import AddProperty from "../../components/AddProperty";
const Properties = () => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Add Property</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="web dev" />
      </Head>
      <h1>Add Property</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the add Property new</p>

      {onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
          {
            <AddProperty />;
          }
        } else {
          <Login />;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very familiar with Firebase but with a quick look at the docks, and being already familiar with React, here is my take.

Any data that effects the way React renders should be loaded in state, in your case, a `useState()` hook.

In Addition, I've basically ripped an example of what you're trying to do straight from the Firebase docs, and used it here. The static function is left outside the component, as it doesn't benefit from a re-render.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import Login from '../Login';
import AddProperty from '../../components/AddProperty';

const auth = getAuth();

const Properties = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(false);
      }
    });
  }, [setUser]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Add Property</title>
        <meta name='keywords' content='web dev' />
      </Head>
      <h1>Add Property</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the add Property new</p>
      {user ? <AddProperty /> : <Login />}
    </>
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

Also I'm not sure of how often you want this user data pulled from a render, so this implementation runs `onAuthStateChanged()` on every render.

Hope this helps. Any issues, just comment and I'll try and help.

Comment: HI yes, I was not aware on the onAuthStateChanged function, I was using something else (auth.currentUser) which was why it was failing.

Comment: Glad I could help. The takeaway here is probably go to the documentation first (even though Google's look pretty bad).

Answer (score 1):

`onAuthStateChanged` returns a function that unsubscribes the registered event handler for listening the firebase auth state. You need to store the authenticated user in a separate state and consume it in a JSX statement.

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from "../../components/firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import Login from "../Login";
import AddProperty from "../../components/AddProperty";

const Properties = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth.currentUser, 
      authUser => {
        setUser(authUser);
      }
    );
    
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [setUser]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Add Property</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="web dev" />
      </Head>
      <h1>Add Property</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the add Property new</p>
      {user ? (<AddProperty />) : (<Login />)}
    </>
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

Comment: when i try this, i get the following error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'onAuthStateChanged')

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to answer this question, as I can't see the entire stack trace. It could possibly be that `auth.currentUser` is undefined? or something else unrelated.